Class not accepting an argument, giving a const constructor error
I am getting this error when I tried calling class this way, the error is caused by UserThreads(scrollController: _scrollController), call. I have also included the userThread class code snipet here:
        //Tab view
        SizedBox(
          height: 1000,
          child: const TabBarView(
            children: [
              UserThreads(scrollController: _scrollController),
              UserReplies(),
              UserMedia(),
            ],
          ),
        ),

The constructor being called isn't a const constructor.
Try removing 'const' from the constructor invocation.dartconst_with_non_const
{required dynamic scrollController}
Type: dynamic
UserThread Class code
 class UserThreads extends StatefulWidget {
   final scrollController;

   UserThreads({
      required this.scrollController
   });

  @override
  State<UserThreads> createState() => _UserThreadsState();
}

class _UserThreadsState extends State<UserThreads> {
  //Initialize all variables
  int? userID;
  String? sessionData;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var scrollController = widget.scrollController;

    return ListView(
      controller: scrollController,
      children: [


remove the const keyword in front of TabBarView  might solve this problem

Does this answer your question? Flutter error : The constructor being called isn't a const constructor

You pass a var to the UserThreads constructor in this line:
'UserThreads(scrollController: _scrollController),'
So, this line is NOT a const statement. Doing this you invalidate the const declaration on this line: 'child: const TabBarView('
That's the reason of the error. So you should reove the const keyword, like this:
    //Tab view
    SizedBox(
      height: 1000,
      child: TabBarView(
        children: [
          UserThreads(scrollController: _scrollController),
          UserReplies(),
          UserMedia(),
        ],
      ),
    ),

if UserReplies and UserMedia are both const, you can modify like this:
    //Tab view
    SizedBox(
      height: 1000,
      child: TabBarView(
        children: [
          UserThreads(scrollController: _scrollController),
          const UserReplies(),
          const UserMedia(),
        ],
      ),
    ),

